# SQL - Where have i gone wrong

Tags: mysql, sql

QUESTION: I need to display the customers name and the total cost of the products they have ordered when they exceed over £10.

I cannot tell if it is because I am trying to use an inner join for three tables?

My attempt:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT Customer.custName,
  SUM(Orders.quantity * Product.cost)
FROM
  Customer,
  Product
  INNER JOIN Orders ON Product.productNo = Orders.productNo
WHERE
  (Product.productNo = Orders.productNo)
  AND (Orders.quantity * Product.cost > 10);
```

Comment: Don't mix explicit and implicit joins. Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax everywhere. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 1):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Plus, use `GROUP BY`.  And your `JOIN` conditions are not complete.  So:

```
SELECT c.custName, SUM(o.quantity * p.cost)
FROM Customer c JOIN
     Orders o
     ON o.customerNo = c.customerNo JOIN
     Product p
     ON p.productNo = o.productNo
GROUP BY c.custName
HAVING SUM(o.quantity * p.cost) > 10;
```

Comment: But don't we need the third JOIN to link the Product table to customers?

Comment: @badcoder11 . . . Not directly.  They are linked by `orders`.